# Help migrating book from TeXTures

Tags: tex-core, eps, specials

I am helping a friend who has to update a book that was originally written in plain TeX using TeXTures quite some time ago.   TeXTures was a very nice TeX implementation for Macs by a company called Bluesky Research.

Helping him seemed to be straight forward.  Just install a newer TeX implementation on his newer OS X machine and off we go. However, the issue that he has is with how he imported EPS images into the book.  These were done with the "special" command and here is a typical example:

```
\vglue 3.0in
\hskip 1.2in
\special{illustration fig.eps scaled 400}
\medskip
```

The book compiles to a dvi file but dvips produces the following errors:

```
dvips: Unknown keyword (illustration) in \special will be ignored
dvips: Unknown keyword (scaled) in \special will be ignored
dvips: Unknown keyword (400) in \special will be ignored
<./fig.eps>
```

I am not a TeX person (used LaTeX for various projects) so I am guessing that the keywords are specific to TeXTures.  The question is this, is there a straight forward way to fix these image imports?  There are many and it is a very large book.  Each image is scaled etc.  I am not sure what "illustration" does.

Thanks
kev

Comment: Untested, but try:  but try: `\special{psfile=fig.eps hscale=50 vscale=50}` This should insert the file scaled at 50%. (Adjust as needed; it's not clear what the 400 means in terms of scale.) For more details see the `dvips` documentation (`texdoc dvips` on most systems, or [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/dvips/dvips.pdf))

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a try.  I believe based on the TeXTures output that the 400 means scale 40%.  I will report back.

Comment: If it works, I can add that as an answer.

Comment: @AlanMunn -- Another approach, although more intrusive, is to `\input{miniltx}` and then work with the `graphicx` package.  Or apply `epsfig`.  (I no longer have the resources to check; this is from memory.)  Or ask the question on the texhax list -- There are several people active there working with plain tex and graphics, as well as former Textures users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My test work perfectly so add it as an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, that was going to be my next suggestion :) but as you say, the direct route is less intrusive.

Answer (score 2):

The `\special` macro passes non-TeX information to `dvips`, and can be used to insert graphics. The corresponding command to your original TeXtures `\special` would be:

```
\special{psfile=fig.eps hscale=50 vscale=50}
```

where 50 = a percentage scaling factor. Since I assume the `scaled` value in the original code is equal `h` and `v` scales, you will need to provide both explicitly in the new command, since `dvips` doesn't recognize a `scaled` key. For more details on what other keys can be used see the [`dvips` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/dvips/dvips.pdf).

It should be fairly simple to do a search and replace in the document to the current syntax.